# Form can't find save method

Tags: django, forms

I've a problem and I don't know where it comes from.

I've this form :

```
class LinkWidgetToDashboardForm(forms.Form):
    widget = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                choices =  [(w.pk, w.name) for w in Widget.objects.all()]
            )
```

Nothing special, but I can't save, navigator returns me

```
'LinkWidgetToDashboardForm' object has no attribute 'save'
```

and in fact if I apply a `dir()` over my form instance, there is no save method.

Just for information

```
def linkWidgetToDashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LinkWidgetToDashboardForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            o = form.save(commit=False)
            o.dashboard = Dashboard.object.get(pk=1)
            o.widget = form.cleaned_data['widget']
            o.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The form class just represents the fields, if you want to save you should create a save function or use a ModelForm which has a save function.

Comment: Should have answered not commented haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to "save" as the field in your form is already populated with the records from the database.

It looks like what you want to do is update the selected object with a dashboard, in that case, use this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    widget = Widget.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['widget'])
    widget.dashboard = Dashboard.objects.get(pk=1)
    widget.save()
```

However, this type of functionality is built-in with `ModelForms`, which are forms that are linked directly to models and have the database save logic.

Answer (score 1):

It is available for `ModelForm` not `Form`. Your form derives from `forms.Form`.

On saving it `ModelForm` will return you the instance of the model that its been defined. Normal form does not know which object to create so they cannot do that.

Refer [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Answer (score 0):

No need for that language here, please.

Only ModelForms have save methods. A normal form doesn't have one, as it makes no sense - what would it save to?